Challenge: Define rounding functions using integer checking functions
This question was inspired by Willans' formula, in which he used the cosine function as a way to constrain a number and floor it to be able to count primes (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5s0h42GfvM): $$p_n = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} ⌊(\frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^i⌊\cos^2(\pi{\frac{(j-1)!+1}{j}})⌋})^{1/n}⌋$$
My goal was to create an integer checking function using no rounding functions or absolute value function. I have already come up with $f(x) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \cos^2(\pi x)^n$, which uses a limit to essentially floor a number between 0 and 1. Note that the function returns 0 for a non-integer, and 1 for an integer.
What other integer checking functions can be made?
Is it possible to define the floor, ceiling, or even round function using an integer checking function such as this? Or as an easier question, is it possible to define the rounding functions, but they are completely pure (by that I mean no modulus, other rounding functions, or any sort of conditional function). An example of an invalid one is: $⌊x⌋ = x - (x\mod 1)$ as it uses modulus as a conditional. The function must also work for all inputs. An example of an invalid function in this context is: $\lfloor \frac{x}{2}\rfloor = \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1 - (-1)^x}{4} $ from how does a floor function work?. The problem with this is that it requires $x$ to be a whole number as $(-1)^x$ will be complex if it is not, so it is not a universal function.

It's good to writing the formula from the video, and give detailed description on what you are looking for.

@LidingYao Thank you, I've updated it
